# c code get pointer variable name within a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

ok guys,
this is a very good question in C code (not c++):

```
void *pName=function();
```

i'd like within "function()" to get the name of the pointer "pName", of course without passing it as an argument string to the same function.

and if you are really so good in C you can provide me the type of pointer, i mean for example:

```
char *pName=function();
```

i'd like to get name and type , so "pName" and "char" within the function.
thank you :)

Comment: One wonders what the thought process was that came to this as a solution?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? And why do you need the name of pName?

Comment: @Skizz [Thought process](http://thedailywtf.com) ?

Comment: No, this is a very good question in C code: `printf("Why?\n");`

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The best you could do is write a macro (shudder) that passes the type and name as arguments to the function without you having to write them a second time.

Comment: Jon this is good, i know macros like __LINE__ or __FILE__ could you give me an example ? why did i post this question : i'd like to trace pointers memory allocation! the classic method char *pName=malloc(1024); won't reveal me if i really free pName next in my code. i'd like to organize a structure with a list of pointers allocated and then check it at the end of code... but in C. is this nosense ?

Comment: @carlobuffa: It's really not a good idea because, to begin with, you can't track allocations using variable names (they can be aliased) and you also cannot *enforce* this scheme. Your C runtime library is very likely to include memleak-detection functionality built-in. How to enable this depends on your compiler.